# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'CreateFile'

Tags: python, createfile

In my notebook I have a dataset and then the implementation to copy the data from that structure to another dataset. When I do this I get the error message "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'CreateFile'". From what I understand the problem is in the key field, but I get the same message:

```
Data columns (total 4 columns):
  # Column Non-Null Count Dtype
--- ------ -------------- -----
  0 reviewId 601786 non-null object
  1 content 600453 non-null object
  2 score 601786 non-null int64
  3 replyContent 47459 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
```

Implementation in Python

```
dfOriginal.to_csv('dfCopia.csv', index=False)
file = "myDrive".CreateFile({'title': 'dfCopia.csv', 'parents': [{'id': reviewId}]})
file.Upload()
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `"myDrive"` is a string.  Did you intend for it to be a variable name?  If so, then remove the quotes. The error message basically told you this:  You're trying to access the `CreateFile` method of a string.  Strings don't have such a method.